# How to Convert String into Salesforce Object Field

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Is it posible to convert a string who has a value of field name into a salesforce object field. For example I have a **String strvalfieldname = 'Desription__c';** and i want it to convert into the **Product custom field Description__c**. is it possible ? .Because in my case the description__c field is a text area and we cannot filter and include a text area into a where clause.

HERE IS MY CODE BUT THIS IS AN ERROR..**Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Object].contains(String)**

```
    String qryTA = 'Description__c';
    String qry = 'Select Id,'+qryTA+' FROM Product__c WHERE '+
                 qryANDbody+qryOR;
    for(Product__c proj : Database.query(qry)){

        if((string) proj.get(qryTA).contains(textareaval)) {
            listentprod.add(proj);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Also, FYI you have a bug in your query string.  You need a ',' and a space after Id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class doesn't compile because you need to case it to a string BEFORE calling `contains()`.

```
 String myTextArea = (String) proj.get(qryTA);
 if(String.isNotEmpty(myTextArea) && myTextArea.contains(textareaval) ) {
```

Comment: We cannot Include a text area field in where clause.. Try it yourself..

Comment: the way your doing it should work fine then

Comment: getting me an error of this **Line: 114, Column: 1: Attempt to de-reference a null object
**

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio what line is 114?

Comment: @DanrylTigolCarpio I'm guessing it was the line in question.  I updated my answer to check for null before calling contains.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps,

```
String textareaval = 'matching value';
String fieldName = 'Name';
String qry = 'Select Id,'+fieldName+' FROM Account ';

for(Account acct : Database.query(qry)){
    String val = (string)acct.get(fieldName);
    if(val.contains(textareaval)) {
        system.debug(' DEBUG HERE : '+(string) acct.get(fieldName));
    }
}
```

Comment: getting me this error **Line: 114, Column: 1
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
**

Comment: This is because you "(string) proj.get(qryTA)" return null and you cannot perform .contains() on a null object.